# Parsing HTML text with JS - Extra Node?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, html-parsing, paragraph

everyone.

I'm building a software that does some text parsing to given HTML texts, and when I save all of the paragraphs from the HTML, I find an extra node.

I've created the

```
 <p id="original_content_js"> Original content via JS:<br> </p>
```

to save the received data from the parsing, and compare it so the data that is parsed (the original text).

This is the HTML code:

```
<p id="original_content_js">
Original content via JS:<br>
</p>

<div id="original_text">    

        <h3>Molly's Sheep</h3>
        <p>
            Molly had a little sheep. <br>
            Molly didn't like her sheep. Ir was too hairy.<br>
            So Molly took a big knife, and cut all of her sheep's fur.<br>
            Now Molly's sheep is cold.<br>
        </p>
        <p>
            But what Molly did not know, was that her sheep is a magical sheep;<br>
            Molly's sheep grows hair instantly, magically!<br>
            Oh, how wonderful, Molly's sheep,<br>
            Making hair, each and each<br>
            Hair grows quickly after cut,<br>
            That's what the story's all about.
        <p>     
    </div>
```

And this is the parsing code:

```
 var html_text_name = "original_text";
 var html_text = document.getElementById(html_text_name);
 var text_paragaphs = html_text.getElementsByTagName("p");
 for (var x=0; x<text_paragaphs.length; x++){
    document.getElementById("original_content_js").innerHTML += "ABC" +
    text_paragaphs[x].innerHTML + "CBA <br>";
 }
```

And the result I get into the original_content_js paragraph is:

```
 Original content via JS:
 ABC Molly had a little sheep. 
 Molly didn't like her sheep. Ir was too hairy.
 So Molly took a big knife, and cut all of her sheep's fur.
 Now Molly's sheep is cold.
 CBA 
 ABC But what Molly did not know, was that her sheep is a magical sheep;
 Molly's sheep grows hair instantly, magically!     
 Oh, how wonderful, Molly's sheep,
 Making hair, each and each
 Hair grows quickly after cut,
 That's what the story's all about. CBA 
 ABC CBA
```

So you can see that I'm getting things as expected - 2 paragraphs wrapped in "ABC" and "CBA", except for having another empty node in the end. Why is there another extra node?

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking that the paragraphs are properly closed. So, your code sees three opening p tags and assumes there are three paragraphs. The very last p tag should be a closed p tag. This is a problem because it sets text_paragraphs to 3 instead of 2. You will need to write a regex to check for this... but beware... writing regex for HTML parsing is a scary thing... and is typically impossible to accurately do 100% of the time.

EDIT: I'm not saying you shouldn't write a regex for checking if tags are properly closed depending on your situation... I'm just saying, be careful.